# @ModelAttribute Overwritten by URL Values

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, mockmvc

I have a controller the following method signature

```
@PostMapping
public String doUpdate(
        @PathVariable("fooId") Long ID,
        @ModelAttribute Item form,
        Model model)
```

The `@RequestMapping` for the controller is

```
@RequestMapping("/foo/{fooId}/Items/{itemId}/type/{type}/update")
```

I am attempting to pass the `@ModelAttribute Item` to the controller via a `mockMvc` and `flashAttr()` as follows

```
 String url = String.format("/foo/%s/Items/%s/type/%s/update", fooId, itemId, type);

 mockMvc.perform(post(url)).flashAttr("form", updateContact))
```

Instead of `form` being populated with data from the `flashAttr` it is being populated `fooId`, `itemId` and `type`

1. Why is this happening and 2. Is there any way around it?

Comment: 1. Because that is the way how the controllers work. They bind parameters to the object. 2 no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@ModelAttibute` in the controller signature is missing a `name` property, so the controller automatically extracts parameters out of the URL and into the `@ModelAttibute`

To work around this, add a name property to the attribute as such: `@ModelAttribute(name = "form")` The `flashAttr` will now map to the `@ModelAttribute` correctly (As long as both share the same name, in this case "form"